# convert string to numeric

Tags: sql, postgresql

please i have a column of table of type numeric. I want to filter on substring and store values in numeric column (val).

how should i do please?

```
create table tab1 (tmp varchar(20), val numeric(4,0));
insert into tab1(tmp, val)

insert into tab1(tmp) values ('exp989');
insert into tab1(tmp) values ('xxx123');
insert into tab1(tmp) values ('xxx098');
insert into tab1(tmp) values ('nat246');

update tab1
  set val = CAST(substring(trim(tmp), 4, 3) as NUMERIC)
  where substring(trim(tmp), 4, 3) ~ '^\s*[0-9]+$';
```

i was surprised that my output is (problem with row3, i expected **098**

**row1: exp989, 989**

**row2: xxx123, 123**

**row3: xxx098, 98**

**row4: nat246, 246**

Comment: im not going to drop it @jarlh . I will not store the same data .

Comment: im not going to store the same data , *row1: exp989, 989.*row2: xxx123, 123 etc..

Comment: ok thank you. Have you an idea about how to fix my problem. ? please..? @jarlh

Comment: Numbers have no leading 0s. 98 *is* 098. If you wanted to store leading zeros you should use a text column

Comment: Store tmp as before, and use https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html for the val column.

Comment: @jarlh i didnt understand what do you mean ? can you explain more please?

Comment: Create the val column as a _generated column_. I.e. a column that doesn't store its own value, instead it _generates_ its value from another column (tmp).

Comment: @Jappa What I understood with your problem is you want to store `098` instead of `98` in `val` column. Am I Correct?

Comment: @AkhileshMishra thats it

Comment: Then this you can not achieve with numeric column. Because Numeric Columns will not store the values with leading Zero. So simply Alter your column `value` to varchar or text. it will be done.

Comment: I'm interested to know what you need to do with this column that makes it important to have the leading zero.  You're allowing the "val" column to be up to 4 digits long, but you were expecting only one leading zero for '098', not two i.e. '0098'? You can also always output the number with leading zeros if you need to e.g. select to_char(98, '000') ==> '098'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the leading zeros, then use a string column.  You can validate that the characters are all digits using a `check` constraint:

```
create table tab1 (
    tmp varchar(20),
    val varchar(4)
    check (val ~ '^[0-9]+$')
);
```

Then you can do the `update` as:

```
update tab1
  set val = substring(trim(tmp), 4, 3)
  where substring(trim(tmp), 4, 3) ~ '^\s*[0-9]+$';
```

Note that there is no conversion to a number.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=262cbea7bd0fcd7a1b2bf85e7f3f58c5) is a db<>fiddle.